# How to find rotation angle of image?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math, image-processing

I'm feeding in a Bitmap image to my C# program to be able to perform OCR to identify the characters in the image. I can do this fairly well if the image is not rotated. One of the program requirements, however, is that the program automatically determines if the image has been rotated, and that it automatically corrects these rotations.

I've tried implementing a simple method where lines are traced across the image and points which contact a character are recorded, and then performing a simple linear regression on the line points. This works to an extent, although it has not proven very accurate due to curvature of characters, etc.

I was wondering if there was a better method to solve this problem? Many thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [gmseDeskew](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13615/How-to-deskew-an-image) algorithm to deskew an image in my program. It works very well.

Comment: This algorithm did the trick for me. I found a great C# implementation [here.](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2010/10/c-how-to-deskew-image.html)Unfortunately, it seems like the algorithm as written is rather hardcoded for ±20 degrees. I tried changing lines of code such as `double cAlphaStart = -20;` to -45 instead, to search for ±45 degrees, and some other lines, but inevitably something would break. I'd love to hear if there's a more flexible algorithm, or someone can explain how to tweak the algorithm to be more flexible without breaking the results.

Comment: I tried it also and it works well. @MacSigler To increase the angle "range" to (-45,+45) it seems you just have to change the lines : double cAlphaStart = -45; int cSteps = 90 * 5; I tested quickly but it seems to be ok.

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting problem to be sure. I'd look for certain letters that are easier to tell rotation for. For example, a capital A or R or K should have both of the lower parts are roughly the same horizontal plane. Another option is to take letters that cannot be identified and rotate them in various ways and re-attempt to identify them. If a letter than could not be identified in the raw scan CAN be identified when you rotate it, that's a pretty big clue. Once you have identified the "correction" rotation that makes a non-recognizable character into a recognizable one, apply the same rotation value to the others.

Comment: adding onto this, if you can locate say an "o", you can radially extend out in one direction and easily determine your orientation by seeing if the letters are on your line

Comment: The biggest problem is that I'm finding it difficult if not impossible to isolate characters before rotation, since I am looking for vertical and hortizontal whitespace between the characters. If the image is rotated, more often than not this whitespace is interrupted by the next character. Since I can't isolate the characters, I can't begin to try to identify them.

Comment: @MacSigler how about a strong-enough blur that would make lines of text appear at least blended together enough for edge detection or to stand out in a hough transform?

Comment: @MacSigler http://www.loni.ucla.edu/~ztu/publication/cvpr12_textdetection.pdf this might help

Comment: @AK4749 It's certainly an interesting paper, but I get lost every time I try to read it. :P

Comment: I would think that isolating a single letter would be relatively easy -- just identify a threshold for "white" and pick a region that is completely surrounded by it.

Answer (score 2):

If it recognizes lines of text, then try to blur the image so that lines are mostly solid and find direction of the lines (either with analysis of Fourier transform or by ridge detection).

Answer (score 1):

If the text is formatted like a printed document (column(s) and lines of text) then you can take advantage of this.

An approach that I've often seen used for document text is to do projection profiles:

1. Scan a document at a specific orientation and sum up the number of "black" pixels on each scan line (creating a 1D array of counts, each index representing a Y coordinate, the profile).
2. Calculate the variance of the counts (profile).
3. Repeat for multiple angles, (can be done in a binary search fashion to reduce processing)
4. The angle that results in the greatest variance is the correct angle (due to the text lines creating large peaks from the printed text, and low valleys due to the absence of text between the lines)

Then after finding this angle you can adjust your image accordingly and do your awesome OCR.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to find the vertical-ish lines that are adjacent to the text (i.e., the left margin).  For each scanline, record the first black pixel.  Put all of those in a linear regression, and you should get a near vertical line.  Measure its angle from true vertical and you should be able to unrotate the text.  You could imagine doing the same thing for the top, bottom, and right sides, too, and taking an average.

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar problem before, and we searched for an easy and quick solution, and we ended up using a commercial toolkit (leadtools). You can use it to do auto processing to the image before OCR it. You can check this [help topic](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/fo/leadtools.forms.ocr~leadtools.forms.ocr.iocrpage~autopreprocess.html) to know how to use this toolkit to process and scan images.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here (and WHY it actually answers the question on *rotating angle*) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid (and downvoted) if the linked page changes. See [How To Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer) for why it is important.